# python uwsgi SSL client cerificate cannot be parsed

Tags: python, ssl, uwsgi

With a verified client cert, I run the following with uwsgi 2.0.19.1

```
import logging

logging.basicConfig(level=logging.DEBUG)
logg = logging.getLogger()

def application(env, start_response):

    for k in env.keys():
        r = '{}: {}\n'.format(k, str(env[k]))
        logg.debug(r)
    s = env['HTTPS_CLIENT_CERTIFICATE']
    logg.debug('foo {}'.format(type(s)))
    f = open('foofoofoo.crt', 'w')
    f.write(s)
    f.close()
    r = s
    l = len(s)
    r = r.encode('utf-8')

    headers = [
                ('Content-Type', 'text/plain; charset=UTF-8',),
                ('Content-Length', str(l),),
            ]
    
    start_response('200 OK', headers)

    return [r]
```

the output of `foofoofoo.crt` cannot be parsed by :

```
openssl -in foofoofoo.crt -text
openssl -in foofoofoo.crt -text -inform der
```

also, the `foofoofoo.crt` file is 1646 bytes, while the crt file I sent with curl is 1753 (although the latter is in PEM format).

I was expecting to get a parseable certificate from this environment variable. Obviously, I'm not, and how do I need to parse it to get the actual parseable value?

---

The first few bytes of the DER format of the cert being sent with curl:

```
tmp $ openssl x509 -in client_demo.crt -outform der | hexdump -C
00000000  30 82 04 e0 30 82 02 c8  02 01 03 30 0d 06 09 2a  |0...0......0...*|
00000010  86 48 86 f7 0d 01 01 0b  05 00 30 81 a1 31 0b 30  |.H........0..1.0|
00000020  09 06 03 55 04 06 13 02  4b 59 31 0f 30 0d 06 03  |...U....KY1.0...|
```

same with the uwsgi end output:

```
(.venv) uwsgi $ hexdump -C foofoofoo.crt 
00000000  30 c2 82 04 c3 a0 30 c2  82 02 c3 88 02 01 03 30  |0.....0........0|
00000010  0d 06 09 2a c2 86 48 c2  86 c3 b7 0d 01 01 0b 05  |...*..H.........|
00000020  00 30 c2 81 c2 a1 31 0b  30 09 06 03 55 04 06 13  |.0....1.0...U...|
```

They are vaguely similar, seems like just an encoding issue really. So how to do the encoding so that the server end can evaluate the cert value properly?

Comment: Looks like a known problem caused by environ being a string (UTF-8) but the data stored are actually binary (i.e. not a UTF-8 string). See https://github.com/unbit/uwsgi/issues/1558 and https://github.com/unbit/uwsgi/pull/2008.

Comment: Adding `r = env['HTTPS_CLIENT_CERTIFICATE'].encode('ISO-8859-1')` makes it work. That's rather hacky, though, to say the least. I tried this hint first, but does not seem to work anymore: https://github.com/unbit/uwsgi/pull/1562 (yielding "cannot load certificate" and still have the bogus utf8 bytes in there).